# C#.NET, Adding AD user to AD group - The object already exists

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, directoryservices, principalcontext

I've been tasked with creating a solution to add and remove AD users to and from AD groups. The following code is functional, except when I try to save the group. I'm getting an exception of "The object already exists." I've narrowed down the issue (I think) to the SamAccountName, and I think that is what is causing the exception.

I don't have access to modify anything in AD aside from the permissions I've been granted to modify the groups designated to have users added/removed from them. I've done endless research, and I just haven't been able to determine a solution. Any help would be deeply appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "address", "DN", "username", "password");
GroupPrincipal grp = new GroupPrincipal(ctx, sGroup);
UserPrincipal usr = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, sUser);
if (grp != null)
{                  
    grp.Members.Add(usr);
    grp.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to me that you are creating a new group with the same name as an existing one. Instead of

```
GroupPrincipal grp = new GroupPrincipal(ctx, sGroup);
```

could you try

```
GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, sGroup);
```

to get the existing group and then modify that?

Comment: I modified the code to match as shown above, I'm getting back the exception "Multiple principals contain a matching Identity."

Comment: You may need to be more accurate in providing sGroup: `GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, sGroup);`. Or provide a distinguished name. Basically you have two objects that AD thinks match whatever you're passing there.

Comment: ***IsMemberOf***
                `var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userId.ToLower());  var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, groupName);
if (group == null || user == null) return false; return user.IsMemberOf(group);`